# In terms of SEO, is it ok to have the same word in singular and plural in the URL?

Tags: seo, url

In terms of SEO, is it ok to have the same word in singular and plural in the URL? For example, I have a website to sell houses but I want to target for "house" and "houses", so if a person search "buy house" or "buy houses" my website can be in the results of Google.

So, is it ok to have a URL like `www.nicehouses.com/house/type1.html`? Would Google process both terms? or will it be treated as spam? Is it a good idea to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whichever URL structure you think is more logical and reads better for your users. Don't think in terms of keywords too much in the URL, especially when dealing with variations of the same word, because:

1. Keywords in the URL count very little towards SEO.
2. Google already knows the relationship between `house` and `houses` (plurals) and is quite likely to return results that contain "houses" when you search for "house" (and vice versa).

Comment: But sometimes if I search the word in singular and then in plural they have different results and the amount of results are also different. Take a look at this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49088/which-is-good-to-target-singular-or-plural-keyword

Comment: Yes, you can certainly get different search results. But singular and plural words can have different meanings which also influences the search. However, you are specifically asking about the URL. The URL should primarily be structured for your users benefit. Your _content_ should target the keywords.

Comment: In other words, what is important is the keywords in the content and not in the url?

Comment: Yes, keywords in the URL carry very little SEO weight these days. Users see the URL in the SERPs, so a user-friendly URL can help with click-through-rates (indirect SEO), but it won't necessarily help you to rank any higher.